# Save an UIImagePicker Video

Tags: video, save, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdictionary

I have searched and searched but can not find a basic `UIImagepicker` video save code.
I have everything set up and just have a blank void.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)
         picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)
              info{
}
```

I know it has something to do with the dictionary, but after that I'm lost, any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code for save the video on photo album.

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        //get the videoURL 
        NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

        if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
        {
                // Copy it to the camera roll.
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), tempFilePath);
            } 
    }

    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    - (void) video: (NSString *) videoPath
    didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error
       contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
        NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error);
    }
```

Comment: Even though I am getting warnings about works, with using a bridge for the final argument, like so:    `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), (__bridge void *) tempFilePath);`