# Cant move saved .mov file to the photo roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have a library which records a video and saves it to the iPad. After it is saved I want to move it into the photo library but I cannot get this to work.

```
 BOOL success = [videoWriter finishWriting];
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"finishWriting returned NO");
        }

    [self cleanupWriter];

    id delegateObj = self.delegate;
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]){
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Failed to save movie");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Saved movie");
        }
    }];
    }
    else{
        if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputPath)){
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputPath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Didn't save movie");
        }
    }
```

This will always return Didn't save movie. This indicates the video is not compatible to be put in the roll. The thing is, I can't see whats wrong with it, because I cannot look at the video until it appears in the roll, since I'm running this on iOS.

I've been stuck on this for a while and I hope someone can give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

try this code -

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath))
        {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You're code is giving me a 'Use of undeclared identifier 'info'' on NSString *moviePath = [[info
Any idea why?

Comment: write above code in -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

Comment: Hmm I don't believe that's a callback being made in my current project... I don't have the user selecting a video, but my library records the screen and saves that to a file. How can I force call the method?

Comment: check this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287413/save-an-uiimagepicker-video

Comment: That is not possible for me. The code I've shown above is compiled into a Library and called from a Unity project. I do not have the ImagePickerControl and I cannot use this in my project. Not in the way it is now anyway. Also, what's the difference with the code you gave me and the code I have, apart from the way used to obtain the URL? My last if and your last if are identical.